# Upsert and Multiple External IDs

Tags: apex, soql

If my object has multiple external ids, how can I perform an upsert based  a specified External IDs?  Thanks

Comment: Please add some context to your question. Are you performing a upsert from Apex as a DML statement? Are you executing this from the API? That will allow folks to give you full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if using Apex -

```
database.upsert(RECORDS,Schema.sObjectField,BOOLEAN ALLorNONE);
```

If using a data loader then you pick the field when it prompts you during the upset process.

Anything else you will need to provide more context as to what exactly you are doing. Either way you NEED to know the which field will be used as the External ID Field before you do the upsert

Answer (score -3):

I found the answer to this question.  Here, I specified that Combine__c is the external id.

database.Upsert(busRec,Schema.Business__c.Combine__c, false);

Comment: Glad you found the solution, and welcome to StackExchange. What do you think about awarding the solution and votes to the [contributor](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/60832/320) who answered your question?